# Is there a way to skip the "Your domain administrator has approved" page in Apps Marketplace Oauth2?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I have a Google Apps Marketplace (v2) app I am working on setting up Oauth2 for.

I've got everything working, but for some reason when I do a redirect to the authentication page, after, after you select which Google account to use (if like you're me and are testing, you have to pick one of several Google accounts you're currently signed into), I get sent to another page which seems utterly pointless:

[image: "Your domain administrator has approved access to" page]

This is bizarre and annoying, because I am logging in *as the domain administrator!*

Does anyone know a way to skip this screen, or what I might be doing to be cursed with this terrible user experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this shows up only if app requests refresh token for offline access. Also this should only appear first time you access the app after installation.

In order to skip this you need to update app to not request refresh tokens.

Answer (score 2):

I just confirmed that having `access_type=offline` will always display this page, even with `approval_prompt=auto`. You will always get back a refresh token as well.

The only way to hide it is to remove `access_type=offline` on future login requests (ask only on signup).