# Specify access_type=online using flow_from_clientsecrets()

Tags: google-api-python-client

I have an application that I have approved as an authorized API client with `openid` and `email` scopes. I still get the "Your domain administrator has approved access" splash screen [as documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25491603/is-there-a-way-to-skip-the-your-domain-administrator-has-approved-page-in-apps). The solution is to not request offline access via the `access_type` parameter.

My authorization flow is built with `flow_from_clientsecrets()`, and I don't see any way to pass the access type as a parameter like with OAuth2WebServerFlow. Is there a way to specify that the application doesn't need refresh tokens with the client library?

Answer (score 2):

I'm just getting into using the Google API Python client library myself and found myself in your exact same situation. From what I've read `flow_from_clientsecrets()` only returns a `Flow` with a basic set of arguments applied. It turns out it's much more simple to just make your own `OAuth2WebServerFlow` object and apply whatever extra arguments you need.

Here's a solution I was able to cobble together after poring over the samples in the googleapiclient and oauth2client libraries:

```
# Returns a flow that will prompt for offline access, thus receiving
# a refresh_token in the auth object that gets returned
def prepare_flow(secrets_path, scope):
    # Grab settings from the client_secrets.json file provided by Google
    with open(secrets_path, 'r') as fp:
        obj = json.load(fp)

    # The secrets we need are in the 'web' node
    secrets = obj['web']

    # Return a Flow that requests a refresh_token
    return OAuth2WebServerFlow(
        client_id=secrets['client_id'],
        client_secret=secrets['client_secret'],
        scope=scope,
        redirect_uri=secrets['redirect_uris'][0],
        access_type='offline',
        approval_prompt='force')
```

You can replace replaced the call to `flow_from_clientsecrets` with a call to the above function:

```
flow = prepare_flow(client_secrets, scope)
```

I just ran a clean authentication using this `Flow` and verified the presence of a refresh_token in the auth payload that was returned from Google.

Comment: approval_prompt='force' should now be prompt='consent'.

Other than that - this helped me a lot :-)